# VS Code prompt changes to dollar sign in terminal. Why? I tried nearly every possible keyboard combination, but I still don't get it

Tags: visual-studio-code

Working with VS Code & occasionally in youtube videos, I see the prompt changes to `$` in the terminal window. I couldn't figure out when and why it changes, but it seems important. Does anyone know how to get it and why it changes? I know it sounds stupid, but it drives me nuts. Thanks a million!!!

Comment: what Youtube video? Is `$` the REPL prompt for some language/tool

Comment: Well, sorry, I can't remember exact videos, I've seen loads of them. Anyway, the way I understood it was that in order to run or test a code, this presenter hits a key combo (I suppose), which changes the prompt in VS Code to $. Only with the $ prompt he/she can  run the said test. This all happens in the VS Code's Terminal window. Usually, the VS Code terminal is in cmd or PowerShell mode/prompt. Sorry, I can't provide you with any other information. Either way, thanks for replying

Comment: open a GitBash or Cygwin terminal, `$` is the bash prompt for non-root users

Comment: Ahh, thanks a lot!!!